# Ajax Login plugin

Tags: login, ajax

Looking for a plugin to get Ajax login functionality - can see a couple in Devote:ee but they seem to be pretty old and looks like a few of them aren't supported and/or have no developer response on the forums there.

Can anyone recommend an actively supported good plugin for this? Thanks!

Comment: I've always had success with FreeMember

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my answer from my comment above down here.

[FreeMember](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember) is a great, free plugin that allows some flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX Auth](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajax-auth) is supported and compatible with latest EE versions. If you need support or have pre-sales questions, email me directly to support@intoeetive.com